# Error while getting children of a body tag from xml using jdom

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I need to walk through a JDOM tree and extract all data from body section to use it in another xml document creation. I'm very new to programming. I have attached my concept and error shown in console. I want to clarify whether this concept is right or wrong. Could any body help me to know about this and give a direction?

Would appreciate any pointers..

```
//root- Existing document's root.
//body- New documents body.
private static Element listChildren(Element root, int depth) {
    System.out.println(root.getName());
    List children = root.getChild("body").getChildren();
    Iterator iterator = children.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
         Element child = (Element) iterator.next();
         System.out.println(child.toString());
         body.addContent(child);
         listChildren(child, depth+1);
         return child;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Error shown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at createXhtml1.listChildren(createXhtml1.java:85)
    at createXhtml1.newXhtml(createXhtml1.java:62)
    at createXhtml1.main(createXhtml1.java:112)
```

Comment: Please post whole sourcecode, or highlight line no. 85.

Comment: Thanks......  List children = root.getChild("body").getChildren();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on comments your problem is with `root.getChild("body")`. This method returns null (there's no child named body in root element). You should check for null and `return null` from method.

```
....
Element element = root.getChild("body")    
if (element == null)
    return null;
List children = element.getChildren();
...
```

**EDIT**
According to comment, you can print (or whatever you want to do) all elements.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><html> <body> <h1 align=\"center\">Profile</h1><hr /> <div class=\"centered\"> <table><tr><td><strong>Name: </strong></td> <td>A</td> </tr> <tr> <td><strong>Age: </strong></td> <td>23</td> <td>programmer</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Email: </strong></td><td>adfg@gmail.com</td></tr></table></div><hr /></body></html>";
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.build(new StringReader(xml));
        listChildren(doc.getRootElement(), 0);
    }

    private static void listChildren(Element root, int depth) {
        System.out.println(root.getName());
        List<Element> children = root.getChildren();
        if (children == null || children.isEmpty())
                return;
        for (Element child : children) {
                 System.out.println(child.toString());
                 listChildren(child, depth+1);
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: but this is my xml file. Definetly it has a body element.          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Profile</h1><hr />
<div class="centered">
<table>

<tr>
<td><strong>Name: </strong></td>

<td>A</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><strong>Age: </strong></td>
<td>23</td>
<td>programmer</td></tr>
\<tr><td><strong>Email: </strong></td><td>adfg@gmail.com</td></tr>
</table>
</div><hr />
</body>
</html>

Comment: Yeah but you calling this method recursively at this line `listChildren(child, depth+1);`. So you take a root then its body then iterates over all children and you calling listChildren again on each child. So problem is that there's no body element inside <hi align="center"> for example.

Comment: Simply there's no body element inside `<h1 align="center">...</h1>` and you want to get one at line 85. Anyway what exactly your program have to do?

Comment: Exactly i want all data from existing doc's body and have to make another doc with that data..

Comment: ya.. i got errorless output when i modified my coding as you suggested.. dut still i couldn't get result. please see my output..<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><head><title>First Try</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><style type="text/css">h1 { text-align: center; } div.centered {text-align: center;} div.centered table { text-align: left;}</style></head><body><h1 align="center">Body part</h1><hr /></body></html>

Comment: @Arun I put a pice of code that prints all elements (you can easly rewrite it to make another doc with its data). You should look at [Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) article to fully understand it.

Comment: That's very kind of you.. Definitly i'll reply you after i went through your article.

Comment: @ Michal Kreuzman i went through recursion. But problem regarding our program is that root.getChild("body")==null. But my xml has root-html,head-head,body-body. then how it become null. In my function root is the parameter and i can also access root inside function, but i can't body elemet. could you give a solution..

Comment: Root is not always your parameter. At first call of `listChildren` method there's body element in root but in second call there isn't because you call method `listChildren` from method `listChildren` too.So focus on line 91 in your program and look what you put like a parameter. It's child of body element (eg. H1) so program nests into `listChildren` again with parameters child (H1) and depth + 1. Then you want to get body from that child element (H1) but there's no element of this name obiviously. That's all. For better imagination use debugger where you can see whole process more clearly.

Comment: Hi @ Michal Kreuzman, Greeting for the day...your assumption is very correct. I think, i can solve that problem by modify my code as List<Element> children = current.getChildren(). But still problem is that in its first call when current Element become root,it's getChildren() method returns null..That is root.getChild("body")==null. Could you identify what is the problem behind it..

Comment: @Arun Hi, in this case please post your full code with input file.

Comment: @Michal Kreuzman Hi, Greetings for the day..I've attatched my full coding at stackoverflow as another qn.Please go through that...